# Do I need JPA provider in google app engine?

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa-2.0

I'm using Google app engine, and I want to use JPA 2 that is supported by it. 
As far as I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) JPA is only interfaces, so, whenever you want to use it you need a JPA provider (such as hibernate), but in the getting started tutorial there are examples without any provider just JPA. 
So, do I really need Hibernate (or any other provider) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google app engine uses datanucleus as the JPA provider. See the example of a `persistence.xml` file they show [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Setting_Up_JPA_2_0). I don't think you have to bundle this provided with your app since it is probably loaded by Google, but I'm not sure about this.